# Java: Confused with these file I/O methods not functioning

Tags: java, file, file-io, exception, io

I'm trying to implement a method to write an array of Song() objects to a file for an assignment. I've become fairly lost on how to achieve this. I want to be able to call the function in the main method but it doesn't appear to do anything. At this stage it is a test where I want it to print on the command line upon running main().
Here's my code:

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
    { //run the main program.
        Interface songUI = new Interface();
        songUI.run();

        try{
        PrintWriter outputTest = null;
        outputTest = write("testfile");
        read();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Caught!");
    }

    }


      public static PrintWriter write (String fileName) throws IOException{

      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);


      PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);

      outFile.println ("Random numbers"); 

      for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      {
          outFile.println ((int)( 1 + Math.random()*10) + " "); 
      }

      outFile.close();
      return outFile;
}
```

I also have a method for reading from the file i'm trying to get working here:

```
public static void read() throws IOException{

        String fileName = "test1";
        System.out.println ("The file " + fileName + "\ncontains the following lines:\n");
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner (new File (fileName));

        while (inputStream.hasNextLine ())
        {
            String line = inputStream.nextLine ();
            System.out.println (line);
        }
        inputStream.close ();
}
```

As you can tell i'm confused, and any help would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to `testfile` but trying to read from `test1`.

The code is poorly organized.

- a method called `write()` shouldn't do anything else, and it should certainly not do input
- returning a closed `PrintWriter` is completely pointless.
- the `write()` method catches `IOException` internally, which makes it impossible for the caller to know about failure. Have it *throw* `IOException` instead, like the `read()` method does, and let the caller deal with it.